# Writing SuperOffice SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for help writing a SQL query for SuperOffice 7 for Windows on MSSQL.
The DB schema diagram is at http://devnet.superoffice.com/Developer/Resource/?entryid=1659&catId=84 > Sales & Marketing Database Tables

Essentially I'd like to extract the CATEGORY.name and CONTACT.name of any CONTACT who has a PHONE.phone matching the input parameter.

This is the closest I have got, but it seems to only work for a subset of the phone numbers in the DB and I'm stumped as to why:

```
SELECT CONTACT.name AS contactname
, CATEGORY.name AS categoryname
, PHONE.phone 
FROM CONTACT 
INNER JOIN CATEGORY ON CONTACT.category_idx=CATEGORY.Category_id 
INNER JOIN PHONE ON CONTACT.contact_id=PHONE.phone_id 
WHERE PHONE.phone=[inputparameter goes here];
```

I realize there is a COM API for this sort of thing but this project requires a pure SQL query.

Comment: Please provide a sample Inputparameter and sample data sets from your table (especially PHONE)

Comment: If it's only working for a subset of the phone numbers, figure out what's common to the numbers that do work and different from the ones that don't. The ERD you linked doesn't give data types, but phone numbers are probably strings (`varchar()`) so you're only matching ones that have the same formatting you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. In case it helps anyone else, the resolution was that the join table needed depends on the value of PHONE.Ptype_idx field. When the value of this field is 1-2, PHONE.owner_id is a foreign key for CONTACT. When it is 1385-16390, PHONE.owner_id is a FK for PERSON.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it;

```
select
    c.name as Contact,
    cat.name as Category,
    ph.phone
from crm7.contact c
left join crm7.category cat ON c.category_idx = cat.category_id
left join crm7.phone ph ON c.contact_id  = ph.owner_id
where ph.ptype_idx < 1000
```

This will get the phonenumber for the company. Notice that you've joined contact_id to phone_id, which is wrong. You have to join it to the owner_id field, and filter on the ptype_idx.